# Key to breezhome lost

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did something ridiculous - I lost the key to my house and I can't get back in. I looked on the wiki and it says Delphine takes it when you go to the Thalmor Embassy, and she puts it in the chest at the Sleeping Giant Inn. I went there to check and it is not there, so I am at a total loss at how to get back in my house.

I am open to using the console commands to spawn the key but I don't know the ID for the key, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Keys#Key_to), the Object ID for the Key To Breezehome is `00093b08`. So, in order to spawn yourself a new one, open the console (by default, bound to <kbd>`</kbd>) and type :

> `player.additem 00093b08 1`